# What are Magnet Links?

Tags: bittorrent

When I download a torrent file there is an option for 'magnet link download'.

What is a 'Magnet Link'? Do they have any extra advantages?

Comment: @Josh: Magnet links concern peer-to-peer clients, which are software.

Comment: yes, valid question for me.

Comment: @akira:, ignacio: I guess I viewed it in a different context.

Answer (score 4):

It is basically a link to a files hash signature not the files location.  You can read all about it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_link).

Answer (score 0):

> A Bittorrent magnet link contains all the information needed to start
>   downloading the files from peers directly. It is a server-less way of
>   retrieving the right information to start downloading the requested
>   files. A magnet link therefor is theoretically all that is needed to
>   download files from other peers in the Bittorrent network. Magnet
>   links can be distributed by email, messaging and other forms of
>   communication but are most often found on the torrent sites that
>   usually offer both torrent and magnet links to their users.
>
> A magnet consists of several parts:
>
> - **magnet**: (This is the magnet link identifier)
> - **?xt=urn:btih**: (Defines a Bittorrent Info Hash, the Edonkey identifier would for instance look like this xt=urn:ed2k:)
> - **5dee65101db281ac9c46344cd6b175cdcad53426** (The content hash)
> - **&dn=name** (The name of the file)
>
> The full magnet link would look like this:
>   **magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5dee65101db281ac9c46344cd6b175cdcad53426&dn=download**.
>   Detailed information about additional Magnet Link parameters are
>   listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme). One useful parameter that has not been
>   mentioned yet is the `as=` parameter which contains encrypted
>   information about a download source. This speeds up the process of
>   finding the first peers.
>
> **Main Advantages of Magnet Links**
>
> The main advantage for Bittorrent indexers is that they do not have to
>   store the torrents on their servers anymore which could be beneficial
>   for them in several ways. It could reduce the pressure from the media
>   creation industry and reduce hardware infrastructure expenses thanks
>   to less tracking and downloading.
>
> The end users on the other hand benefit from Magnet Links as well. All
>   they need is the link to start downloading the files which makes them
>   independent from torrent indexers. It also allows them to distribute
>   the information more easily. Torrent indexers remain on the other hand
>   the main source of information for new files that are available for
>   download.
>
> **Magnet Links use DHT**
>
> A tracker less environment should raise a question of identification.
>   How can a download be initiated ff there is no tracker to inform the
>   Bittorrent user about other users who download and seed the file? The
>   answer is DHT, Distributed hash tables. DHT is enabled by default in
>   popular clients such as uTorrent or Vuze. Without going into to much
>   detail, the hash of the magnet link is used to find peers using DHT.

<sub>[Source](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/05/what-is-a-magnet-link-and-how-does-it-differ-from-torrents/)</sub>